# How to use 12 digit number in C?

Tags: c, digit

I am dealing with a math example. I need to use 12 digit number for my code. So which datatype should i use, to use the number in my functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64-bit integers (`long`, `int64_t`, `unsigned long`, `uint64_t`) should do the trick, or if you need decimals, `double` or `long double`.

Comment: If you need decimals you're out of luck in pure C; `double` and `long double` are floating point types, not decimal ones.

Comment: No. I *did* mention 64-bit integers too, which can hold well over 12 digits even when signed!

Comment: what should i use for example while printing them? "%ld" was for long as far i remembered?

Comment: Yes. `%ld` is the correct format specifier. Use `%lu` if it's an `unsigned long`, however.

Comment: Check out `<inttypes.h>`. It has printf() / scanf() format specifiers for the intX_t types (among others).

Comment: You should not recommend `long` as a 64-bit type. It's 32-bit on most systems and the C standard only requires it to be at least 32-bit.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a 64-bit integer type, I'd go with that, since it gives you the (18 full digits) range:

```
−9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to
+9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

For other tasks (even bigger integers or massive floating point values), I use [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), the GNU multi-precision library. It's performance is impressive.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use "unsigned long long" with format specifier "llu". It works fine for 12 digit number in C.

```
unsigned long long i=600851475143;
printf("%llu",i);
```